# Move from angular 2 and webpack 1, to angular 6 and webpack 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

lately I move from angular 2 and webpack 1, to angular 6 and webpack 4 but unfortunately I did't meet the best dependencies, is any suggestion for best dependency for angular 6 and webpack 4?? if there any article or tutorial that have topic or example dependency on package.json, I will gratefull :)

Comment: Honestly, I would run up a new Angular 6 project and move your stuff over by hand. Sound like a big hassle but will be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the very awesome guide provided by the angular community itslef during migrating your projects from one version to 6 . Guide link : https://update.angular.io/

Comment: 2 to 6 is too big a jump, if you haven't kept your project up to date it really is best to run up a new project and move the parts over by hand.